# MySQL: DELETE FROM using a multi conditional "not equal to" WHERE

Tags: mysql, database, sequelpro

Hah. So. I've been playing with this particular query where I'm trying to delete a large swath of rows but I end up not doing what I'm expecting. I've run various variations of this query and I'm not having any luck.

Basically I'm trying to do this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE country <>  'MX' OR 'CA';
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE foobar NOT IN ( 12 OR 5 );
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE foobar NOT IN ( 'foo' ) OR ( 'bar' );
```

And a couple other ideas I had that weren't working. I'm just uploading a fresh dataset for the umpteenth time I'd appreciate some help in the right direction.

Comment: A quick look to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) always helps.

Comment: Well. Egg on my face. Thank you for this, I've been scouring the DELETE FROM section and couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, logical operators like "OR" are applied to conditions but not values.

So, you can use either

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE country <> 'MX' AND country <> 'CA';
```

or

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE country NOT IN ('MX', 'CA')
```

The second one is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 DELETE FROM table WHERE country NOT IN ('MX', 'CA');
```